# Filling UIBezierPath results in pixelated image from image context

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgcontext, uibezierpath

I have implemented a very simple filled in circle using `UIBezierPath`, which I then convert to `UIImage` so that I can set that to a `UITableViewCell`'s `imageView`. This works really well, but you can see the edges are pixelated on a Retina display. Why is that, what can be done to ensure it looks fantastic?

```
let colorSize = cell.frame.size.height - 20
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, colorSize, colorSize)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: (colorSize)/2).addClip()
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
var colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
cell.imageView?.image = colorImage
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1.  Read the [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext):

> This function is equivalent to calling the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` function with the opaque parameter set to `false` and a scale factor of `1.0`.

Step 2. Follow the link to the [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions), which says:

> *`scale`*   The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of `0.0`, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

Step 3. Try using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with a scale of `0.0`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
```

Step 4. Profit…?

Comment: -1 for being snarky.

Comment: +1 for including step 4